# Django admin: Change the displayed value of a key

Tags: django, django-admin

i have a model that includes a key "service_id" and the values stored in database are like "10001", i want to add a method to admin page that instead of displaying the id it displays a custom value like "Car Wash".

Comment: Where in the admin do you want to do this? List page? Edit page? Also, is this custom value part of a field with `choices`? Post your Model and your Admin classes.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to create a [custom field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) to be added in your `list_display`

```
from django.contrib import admin

@admin.register(MyModelClass)
class MyModelClassAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('my_field')

    def my_field(self, obj):
        return obj.description().title()
    my_field.short_description = "My field"
```

You can change the value returned by the `my_field` method as you prefer (take into consideration that you can use the `obj` instance).

Answer (score 0):

Create an Admin Class following

```
class ModelclassNameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('service__name', [other fields])
```

in it for list display use double underscore `__` for accessing field inside foreign key like `service__name`

and while registering the model add admin as second argument.

```
admin.site.register(ModelclassName, ModelclassNameAdmin)
```